# Preparing the dictionary from a django query object

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I have a Db table where data are stored in the below format.

```
+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| id      | category                                  | categ_rules |
+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
|       1 | A                                         | Invetory    |
|       2 | A                                         | Index       |
|       3 | B                                         | Organic     |
|       4 | B                                         | Shuffle     |
|       5 | B                                         | Parag       |
|       6 | C                                         | Numero      |
|       7 | C                                         | Rugby       |
|       8 | D                                         | Amdar       |
|       9 | D                                         | Rutha       |
|      10 | D                                         | Athens      |
+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

I want to prepare a dictionary in the below format

```
{
    'category': A,
    'rules_data': [{'rules_id': 1, 'categ_rules': Inentory},{'rules_id': 2, 'categ_rules': Index}]
}
```

... and similarly for category B, C, D

I have written a django query to pull all the data

```
rules_data = CatRule.objects.all()
```

How can loop through the object and build the data above format.

Comment: This question is answered by reading the official Django and python documentation.

Comment: What do you mean where? are you actually working on a Django project without knowing where the documentation is?

Comment: @petkostas, I mean that answering 'go read the docs' brings no actual value to the thread.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here to code for you, this is not an actual problem where you tried anything and ask for help, looping over a  queryset and manipulating data is a straightfoward task clearly explained in Django documentation, if you don't know how this is done then clearly you haven't spend that much time reading the docs.

Comment: @petkostas, since everything in programming comes down to looping, conditional execution and data manipulation, does that mean that no questions about programming are allowed here? All those concepts are explained in detail in every single programming book.

Comment: @kroolik this is not the case you know that, the example clearly shows that the user did not even try the obvious, if you check my answers you will see I have answered previously simpler questions where actually the user did try to do something but failed, asking how a loop is dealt with does not feel to me as a question where the user did his best.

Comment: @petkostas, then perhaps instead of saying 'go read the docs', a more appropriate would be to ask 'What have you tried already?'. Perhaps, the OP had few attempts but just didn't include.

Comment: @kroolik "what have you tried" is specifically banned as a comment on SO.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, what about 'What were your previous attempts that have clearly failed that lead you to ask this question in this place?'

Comment: @kroolik http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @petkostas, basing on the article, a perfectly viable comment would be 'What difficulties prevented you from solving the problem yourself?. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions on SO.'. At this point, I can't see a close option saying 'Did not include failed attempts to solve the problem' neither it is sufficient to say that the OP doesn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is similar to the ur row from the query
note bring only category,ruleid,categ_rules from ur query in simillar order

```
 a=[[1,'A','Inv'],[2,'A','Index'],[3,'B','Orga']]


values = set(map(lambda x:x[1], a))
dict=[]
for x in values:
    temp={}
    temp['catogory']=x
    temp['rules']=[]
    for y in a:
        if y[1]==x:
             temp['rules'].append({'ruleid':y[0],'categ_rules':y[2]})
    dict.append(temp)
print dict

#output=[{'rules': [{'categ_rules': 'Inv', 'ruleid': 1}, {'categ_rules': 'Index', 'ruleid': 2}], 'catogory': 'A'}, {'rules': [{'categ_rules': 'Orga', 'ruleid': 3}], 'catogory': 'B'}]
```